# Is it possible to configure Reporting Services to emit browser compatibility headers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

We have a dashboard that hosts some Reporting Services (2008) reports within frames. The dashboard runs in the browser's standards compliance mode, but this is causing some of the reporting services reports to break in unexpected ways; for example, a table of static text isn't maintaining the column widths, and embedded images aren't being sized correctly.

The solution appears to be to add either a real HTTP header (`X-UA-Compatible: IE=7`) or as a meta tag within the page. Is it possible to configure Reporting Services to add this header?

Comment: I wonder if you could run this through IIS somehow. It's trivial to add an HTTP header in that.